# MySQL wont launch on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I use to be able to host a symfony/php project locally, but recently mySQL wont launch. Ive looked online and checked my logs, but I'm not really sure how to solve this.

Heres my mySQL log:

```
2019-07-12 19:14:03 3298 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-07-12 19:14:03 12952 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: maybe it has to do with your memory.

Comment: @JinLee Should I increase swap space?

Comment: yeah, play around with memory setting a little.  could help maybe? not  sure though :( nothing to lose.

Comment: increase buffer pool

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/368223  here you go